# Can you manipulate a person with a death note, if the cause of death is a disease?

Tags: death-note

If John Zeurto wrote something like this:

> Bob Doe Bradykardie. At 11:30pm Bob Doe sends a list of every SPK member to the
>   email address: blala@gmail.com.

Is it possible to manipulate someone with the Death Note when the cause of death is a long-term disease and not an immediate, violent end?

Comment: How is this consistent with your title? Here it looks like it's just similar to what Light did to Ray Penber (not sure about the spelling), but the title of your question suggests the problem is different.

Comment: i edited it. i hope someone you understand it now

Comment: As long as it physically isn't impossible (e.g. Bob doesn't know the names, or the disease always takes a very long time to kill people), it should be fine.

Comment: Can the death note be used as a mind control tool if you write an novel on how and what the person does before dying of something as long as all the actions and cause of death are possible?

Comment: why does everyone dislike this answer?

Comment: People dislike your post because it's not clear what you're asking. Are you asking whether it's possible to manipulate someone with the Death Note when the cause of death is a long-term disease and not an immediate, violent end? If so, I would edit your post and make that much more clear. As it is, you shove that detail in at the end, so it looks like it's just an incidental detail and not a major part of your question.

Comment: I downvoted because I didn't understand the question. Also just because you always say 'come on. no one?' straight after you ask a question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

While the second rule given here clearly states that the Death Note can only operate within 23 days (in the human calendar), according to the next rule, if the specified disease takes more than 23 days then the human will die according to the time required by the disease.

[image]

However, whether or not you can manipulate the human during that extra (after 23 days) time period is not specified in any of the rules.

Personally, I think it would be beyond the scope of the Death Note to do so.

Comment: so you can't manipulate a person when you kill it via disease?

Comment: What I'm saying is, that if you specify a long term disease, like in your original question, it is uncertain whether you would be able to control the human for the entirety of the period. 
Also, you have to specify all the details of the person's (possible) actions within 6 minutes and 40 seconds and you can't dictate all his actions for his complete lifetime (specified by disease) in that much time.